# TestNg Console App with Exit

Tags: java, java-8, testng, console-application

I am trying to write a TestNgtest case for a console app for when the user inputs `ESC`. At which point the application should print a message and then exit. I want the TestNg to test if the message gets printed. Here's the app code:

```
public class Application {
  public static void doSomething(Scanner scanner) {
    String inputString = scanner.nextLine();

    if("ESC".equals(inputString.toUpperCase())) {
        System.out.println("Bye");
        System.exit(0);
    }
  }
}
```

Here's the junit code:

```
public class ApplicationTest {
    private Application app;
    private ByteArrayInputStream in;
    private ByteArrayOutputStream out;

    @BeforeMethod
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        app = new Application();
        out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        System.setOut(new PrintStream(out));
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        System.setIn(System.in);
    }

    @Test
    public void testESCInput() throws Exception {
        in = new ByteArrayInputStream("ESC".getBytes());
        System.setIn(in);
        app.processInput(new Scanner(System.in));
        assertTrue(out.toString().contains("Bye"));
    }
}
```

But since the application exits with `System.exit` I don't even get to the `assertTrue` line, the TestNg just ends before that. Is there a right way to test this?

Comment: You could externalize the behavior when esc is pressed into another class, possibly a `Runnable`. Then, you could just provide a mock implementation for testing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `SecurityManager` to reject exit attempts, then build tests around the expected exception, e.g. this works with JUnit, should be easily adapted to TestNG

```
public class ExitTest {
  public static class RejectedExitAttempt extends SecurityException {
    private int exitStatus;
    public RejectedExitAttempt(int status) {
      exitStatus=status;
    }
    public int getExitStatus() {
      return exitStatus;
    }
    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
      return "attempted to exit with status "+exitStatus;
    }
  }

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
    System.setSecurityManager(new SecurityManager() {
        @Override
        public void checkPermission(Permission perm) {
            if(perm instanceof RuntimePermission && perm.getName().startsWith("exitVM."))
                throw new RejectedExitAttempt(
                    Integer.parseInt(perm.getName().substring("exitVM.".length())));
        }
    });
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    System.setSecurityManager(null);
  }

  @Test(expected=RejectedExitAttempt.class)
  public void test() {
    System.exit(0);
  }
}
```

This is a simple test, that is satisfied with any exit attempt. If a particular exit status is required, you have to catch the exception and verify the status.

Since this custom `SecurityManager` allows any other action, resetting the security manager to `null` is possible.